# How do I preprocess `data` in address.call.value()(data)

Tags: solidity

I have a transaction struct `tx` which contains `to`, `value` and `data` and is executed with `tx.to.call.value(tx.value)(tx.data)`.

In Solidity, how do I preprocess `data` to take a function name and arguments of `to`?

I understand (perhaps incorrectly) that data needs to be RLP encoded.

Comment: duplicate of [How does one dynamically craft message data for a transaction in Solidity?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/how-does-one-dynamically-craft-message-data-for-a-transaction-in-solidity/6139)